# How do I sort a single string output in ASCII descending order through a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, sorting, ascii

I have a string of words and im trying to do a count for each alphabet to obtain the individual letter counts. However, I would like to order them in ASCII in a descending order. This there anyway to modify my function below such that I can obtain my desired output? Print count(word1).sort() doesn't work too as sorting cannot be performed in a single str.

```
word1 = iLoveCats

def count(i):
word2 = Counter(i).most_common()
return " ".join("{}:{}".format(a, b) for a, b in word2)



print count(word1)
```

Current output:

```
a:1 C:1 e:1 i:1 L:1 o:1 s:1 t:1 v:1
```

Desired output:
    Counts in ASCII descending order.

Comment: I would be really helpful if you can provide your sample desired output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map`:

```
def count(i):
   word2 = map(lambda x: map(str,x),Counter(i).items())
   return " ".join(sorted(map(':'.join,word2),reverse=True))
```

Or comprehensions:

```
def count(i):
   word2 = Counter(i).items()
   return " ".join(sorted(['{0}:{1}'.format(*i) for i in word2],reverse=True))
```

Now:

```
print count(word1)
```

Both Reproduce:

```
v:1 t:1 s:1 o:1 i:1 e:1 a:1 L:1 C:1
```

Comment: OP wants sorted ASCII desc as desired output

Comment: @vash_the_stampede Then what you think is desired outout?

Comment: `Desired output: Counts in ASCII descending order` so I would say lower case followed by Upper case?

Comment: nice looks familiar, I've seen this result some where before hmmm :)

Comment: @vash_the_stampede Well, only thing is that still joins :-)

Comment: didn't think it could be done like that, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to place your letter in ASCII descending order, you can use the `chr` and `sorted` functions.

```
word_dict = {...} # your current set of counts

for letter in sorted(word_dict.keys(), key=chr):
    print("%s: %d" % (letter, word_dict[letter]))
```

That should work for your use case.

Comment: word_dict = Counter(word1)

for letter in sorted(word_dict.keys(), key=chr):
    print("%s: %d" % (letter, word_dict[letter]))

Do you mean this? It gave me a type error.

Comment: `word_dict` represents your dictionary of counts.  If you need to, cast it to a dictionary.  This is not your counter code.  This sorts the result of that code in order.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted and count should do the trick here

```
print(' '.join(sorted(['{}:{}'.format(i, w.count(i)) for i in w], reverse=True)))
```

> ```
> v:1 t:1 s:1 o:1 i:1 e:1 a:1 L:1 C:1
> ```

Comment: @u9-forward I would say it should look like this ? also thank you for that little pointer about printing `True` and `False` I'm new wasnt aware

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use sorted($your_list, reverse=True)?

For example:

```
>>> b
['aa', 'BB', 'bb', 'zz', 'CC']
>>> sorted(b,reverse=True)
['zz', 'bb', 'aa', 'CC', 'BB']
>>>
```

`sorted(reverse=True)` could output list b in ASCII descending order.